# certutil -hashfile : processing multiple files in a drag-dropped folder

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, md5, certutil

I'm trying to create a batch script that runs `certutil -hashfile MD5` on each file in a folder and write the output to a file.

I have this code below except it only works on the files in the current folder,
I would like it to work such that when a folder is drag-dropped into the batch file .bat it processes that folder only.

```
for %%a in (*) do certutil -hashfile %%a MD5 >> MD5_log.txt
```

Also is there a way to get it to output spaces in the log file between iterations of the `certutil` output text?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very simple!

---

Simply change `(*)` to `("%~1\*")` or other command-line arguments. If you have multiple drag-drop folders, do `"%~1\*" "%~2\*"`, etc. Using quotes (`"`) can prevent issue with space. So paths are now quoted. And `%%a` becomes `%%~a`, which means to de-quote.

Alternatively, you can set a variable containing all paths and process them one by one.

Result:

```
for %%a in ("%1\*") do certutil -hashfile "%%~a" MD5 >> MD5_log.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Store following file as .bat file and change testfolder and outputfile as desired.

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Set the variables for this script.
set testfolder=C:\Test\
set outputfile=md5_files.txt

cd %testfolder%

echo > %outputfile%

for %%f in (".\*.*") do (
   certutil -hashfile %%f SHA1 >>%outputfile%
   echo %%ff
)



PAUSE
```

Comment: This doesn't solve in any way the question. The question is about drag&drop a folder on the batch file